# is it the fibonacci algorithm without recursion linear?

Tags: recursion

I know that the fibonacci algorithm can be programmed without recursion like this:

```
int fibo(int n){
 if(n <= 1){
  return n;
 }
 int fibo = 1;
 int fiboPrev = 1;
 for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i){
  int temp = fibo;
  fibo += fiboPrev;
  fiboPrev = temp;
 }
 return fibo;
}
```

and also that the recursive fibonacci has a complexity of O(2^k) approximately, but for what I see the non-recursive algorithm is O(n); so it seems is way more efficient, is it ok my calculus or is there any hidden complexity on the non-recursive solution?

Comment: Different algorithms can have different complexities, even if they compute the same thing. Ex. there's several `O(n^2)` sorting algorithms, and also several `O(n log n)` sorting algorithms.

Comment: Also take a look that fibonacci number can be expressed as a single, non-recursive equation: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the complexity of the implementation on its own. In this case, the complexity related to the input n is defined by the for loop, which is directly proportional to the size of n. Therefore, the complexity is O(n) - linear.

Comment: But there's an additional factor here: the number of bits in a Fibonacci number increases as the sequence goes on. So the complexity of calculating one is linear for constant bit size (and therefore with a limit on the count of numbers that can be calculated), but with variable bit size it will not be linear.